# Are there any cons to using color names in place of color codes in CSS?

Tags: css, colors

For example writing `red` is more efficient than `#cc0000`. It has less characters, takes up less space, and is easier to remember.

Are there any down sides to using [color names](http://www.somacon.com/p142.php) over hex codes or RGB values? This includes programming in a multi-developer environment.

Comment: Legetimate question. No reason for a down vote. I'll +1 to bring balance back to the force.

Comment: However, writing red is only slightly more efficient than righting #C00. Shorthand notation is beautiful.

Comment: Hooray Im Helping - i just given an example.

Comment: Because the client will take a while to download 4 more bytes..

Comment: `black` and `white` would certainly be color names which can be used in every situation, since those "colors" will never change their hex code and everybody knows what they have to expect with them (you might not know what you'll get with `orange`). In most cases, I'd prefer using the hex code though, since it's not really good practice to write `color: #39f5d2` in some places and then just have `color: black` in others -> keep consistency. Also writing #000 instead of black is less code after all.

Comment: @user216441 Because at a big website with high access rates, let's surprisingly exemplify at Google, 4 *more* bytes would be at an estimated 6,000,000,000 searches a day without client-side caching over 20 GB data to be transferred.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Different browsers may not agree on what some color names mean. There are not names for all 16 million 24-bit colors. In fact there are only 17 W3C-standard color names. It's probably OK to use those.

Personally I use a templating system at build time to pre-process my CSS files, so that I can keep a standard set of site colors and refer to them by name. That way I get the best of both worlds: I know exactly what my RGB color values are, but I can use simpler names in the CSS.

(Of course, it's still not possible to know *exactly* how a color will look on a given user's browser.)

*edit* — in the 5 years since this answer was written, preprocessors like Less and Sass have become pretty common. Those provide some very sophisticated tools for managing colors (and many other things) in CSS sources.

*edit more* — ok in the 8 years since then, the color names have become standardized. The answer from "Liyali" is much more up-to-date.

Comment: CSS 2.1 defines the names and values of 17 colors: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-color (orange was added in 2.1). I tend to use color names when one is available.

Comment: Thanks - serves me right for quoting w3schools without checking a real authority first (they forgot "orange") - answer fixed.

Comment: i think it has also old info http://www.morecrayons.com/palettes/colorNames/w3c.php

Comment: And what about this list http://www.crockford.com/wrrrld/color.html ? and this http://www.somacon.com/p142.php Do you mean all browser will render same color for 17 W3C colors , and for other color names it's not a gurantee?

Comment: That is exactly right. It's not a standard, so you're taking a risk by relying on it. Now, you're free to do so, and of course you can test the colors that you actually use.

Comment: @Pointy- and non w3c color names can create problem in css validation?

Comment: Well they're not strictly-valid CSS.  The color names in the W3C spec are just those 17, plus the "system color" names that refer to colors of system-supplied graphical elements. I don't know whether validators really complain about that however.

Comment: Point- this article says it will not a problem with other colors http://www.colorschemer.com/blog/2007/07/24/140-named-colors/ will try with validators.

Comment: Well it's your website, so you code up your colors however you like :-)  In my experience, none of the colors in my current site (other than "black" and "white") are in the list anyway.

Comment: This is outdated nowadays, as the CSS standard defines the X11 colors (of which there are 147) as noted in other answers. Browsers will not show different RGB values for those.

Comment: @MarcusOtter yea, unsurprising as the answer is from 2010 :)

Answer (score 16):

I recommend that you follow the W3C recommendations:

All of them (CSS Level 1, Level 2 and Level 3) indicate that using color names is perfectly acceptable, but which ones are acceptible varies depending on the specification.

### CSS1 Specification

[CSS1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#color-units) recommends to use **color names** as a valid substitute to hex codes and RGB codes.

> **6.3    Color units**
>
> The suggested list of keyword color names is: aqua, black, blue,
>   fuchsia, gray, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver,
>   teal, white, and yellow. These **16 colors** are taken from the Windows
>   VGA palette, and their RGB values are not defined in this
>   specification.

### CSS2 Specification

You can use the color name `orange` now! The count is up to **17 colors**. [CSS2 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#color-units) for reference.

### CSS3 & X11 Colors

CSS3 allows for SVG 1.0's [**X11 colors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color) to be used for CSS's properties (as well as `hsl()` values). This expands the amount of color names to **147 colors**. Any of these color names can be used in any browser that supports the SVG 1.0 specification, which is [IE9 or newer](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).

This also means that the list of colors provided in the question are mostly ***not valid***.

### Suggested Usage

If you're seeking to support legacy browsers stick to the web safe original 16 color names since X11 colors are not supported. Otherwise, you are free to use any of the 147 color names specified in the X11 spec.

All browsers should abide by the specification in reference to the equivalent hex codes. The time it takes the parser to read the color names is virtually, if not exactly, the same as using a hex value, an rgb value, or an hsl() value.

To me, it's more readable to write your HEX codes in lowercase. For example, #8b88b6 is obviously more readable than #8B88B6. Also, I tend to use shorthand HEX color instead of full code (#666 instead of #666666) since it's more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

personally, i prefer using hexcodes because of 2 reasons

1. it's easier to copy a hexcode from Photoshop
2. you can use hexcodes throughout a stylesheet but you'll have to mix two styles (hexcodes and color names) otherwise. so your stylesheet can be more uniform/consistent.

This assumes you're using colors other that the simple red, black, white etc. In a multi-developer environment, i'd say hexcodes are better because they're more universally consistent (every developer knows exactly what the color is).

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers look outdated by now.

If you develop for browsers that support CSS3, which are all major browsers since IE9, you can use color names in CSS. In HTML, only the 16 original web colors are supported.

The question was if there are downsides. I think there are a few:

- I find some of the color names are just wrong. Examples:

  - Azure is generally considered a much darker color.
  - Lawn green is nothing like a lawn I've ever seen.
  - Violet looks more like what I'd call pink.
- It is more difficult to create a slightly darker or lighter version of the color by changing its hex values. For instance, a darker variant of #DCDCDC would be #DADADA, but if I would have started with the color name gainsboro, I wouldn't have any idea.
- Javascript calculations are more difficult on a name.

Sources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value and
http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20colors

Comment: Also, perhaps even more confusing/wrong: `darkgray` (`#a9a9a9`) is lighter than `gray` (`#808080`)!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a further optimization, `#c00` for red.  If you are going to use a primary color, or any color that is similar to `#aabbcc`, you can use shorthand, `#abc`.

Comment: but red is easy to remember specially in multi-developer environment

Comment: Efficiency is a relative term!  if making things easier to remember improves your development efficiency, go for it!  If it's bandwidth you're trying to optimize, use the shorthand.

Comment: How do you figure this shorthand optimizes *bandwidth*? The bandwidth would be negligible over a 28.8 kbps connection. And not very many people have those anymore. The browser is just going to [convert that shorthand notation to the long version](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/PR-css3-color-20101028/#numerical) anyway. And under your crazy micro-optimization perspective, it would make more sense to minimize the amount of work the browser has to do to parse your CSS...

Comment: The bandwidth remark was off-the-cuff.  Interesting fact about the browser conversion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use color names for prototyping, debugging, and to set up really basic, monochromatic color schemes which are then ripe for theming with hyper-specific hex colors. It makes a theme-able property easy to spot. It's also more human readable; less brain strain when trying to instantly visualize what's going on.

```
.component {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

...then in theming file...

```
.some-theme .component {
    background-color: #5f5f5c;
    color: #fafafc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to your coding style.  I stick to hex values for consistency - a color is always formatted as `#000` or `#000000`, and I don't have to worry about switching between namd and unnamed colors.

In the end, it's a decision you and your team will have to make on your own.  It's all about your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer all colours in a CSS file to be defined in the same way, if possible.

That way I don’t have to think in a different way when I see different colours defined (e.g. `red`, `#cd876f` and `rgba(255,255,0,0.4)`).

I also prefer colour notations that match what I’ll see when identifying the colour in the design I’m implementing. Photoshop’s colour palette gives RGB and hex values, amongst others, but doesn’t give CSS colour names. (Other design tools might do though.)

Answer (score 0):

I think color names are more descriptive... And this is a good reason for using it when possible.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion it's a matter of preference.  if the color is as simple as red, black, grey, blue, white etc.  ill use the word instead of the hex.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using hex codes is more useful than color names because let's say if you want use red color and you use "red" for color value, but you don't like that predefined red color, you want something lighter or darker so hex codes are really Good for that.

Once you have your own red color of choice, you will remember that hex code everytime you want to use it rather than using the color name.