# background-color: white - ok or should hexidecimal be used?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any cons to using color names in place of color codes in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230851/are-there-any-cons-to-using-color-names-in-place-of-color-codes-in-css)

When specifying colors and background colors in CSS, is it ok to use words like 'white' rather than the hexidecimal value? It seems to work fine for me but are they any issues with other devices or older browseres?

Thanks

Comment: Here's an example of a problem caused by using a named colour such as `white` whereas `#fff` works fine: http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/c34c75ad8d431544?pli=1 - yes it's very narrow and nothing to do with CSS, but still..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from the W3C specification. And it clearly tells that names are depreciated. Its only kept for legacy reasons.

```
Techniques:

Use numbers, not names, for colors.
Example.

Use numbers, not names, for colors:

   H1 {color: #808000}
   H1 {color: rgb(50%,50%,0%)}
Deprecated example.

 H1 {color: red}
Use these CSS properties to specify colors:

'color', for foreground text color.
'background-color', for background colors.
'border-color', 'outline-color' for border colors.
For link colors, refer to the :link, :visited, and :active pseudo-classes.
```

Answer (score 2):

Color shoud be used with **HEX value** not by name, coz that  has been deprecated; see the latest document:

#### http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#style-color-contrast

Comment: That document is accessibility guidelines from 2000 (although still the latest version of that document). Color names are still supported in CSS and are included in the CSS3 specification so are not deprecated. For accessibility guidance is is suggested not to use color names.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of colors that are defined within the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#color-units) so any CSS compliant browser will display your color correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like using the color name when possible. Even though the hexidecimal value is pretty obvious that its white/black, I do find it much easier to pick out the color when its white. That being said, I don't think there are names for all of the colors, so sometimes hexidecimals are necessary.

But in the end, both are acceptable.