# cannot link css with IE, works with chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn CSS, and I'm getting stuck one of the most first part, to include CSS.
The code works perfectly with Chrome, but I cannot get it to work in IE. Considering IE still has high marketshare, I want to make sure I have enough knowledge to support the platform. Is there anyway to know why it is not working?

Below is the html with link to css stylesheet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Adding CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" style="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Adding CSS to the Page!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non diam justo. Integer accumsan lacus ut quam pulvinar ullamcorper. Proin imperdiet mauris ac lectus blandit adipiscing. Vestibulum placerat mi sit amet odio luctus quis aliquam ante tristique. Praesent sem ligula, rhoncus quis gravida vitae, consequat id odio.</p>
  <p>Etiam eros nisl, pretium nec suscipit ac, gravida quis velit. Phasellus adipiscing ultrices lorem, ut porttitor tellus interdum eu. Fusce auctor, felis vitae adipiscing vulputate, tellus odio venenatis lorem, et pretium lectus justo vitae ipsum. Mauris in dictum dolor. Sed fermentum, dolor nec mollis lobortis, eros augue laoreet tortor, vel cursus neque sem ac diam.</p>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Praesent sem ligula rhoncus</li>
    <li>Donec ut ipsum at quam</li>
    <li>Maecenas libero neque accumsan ut</li>
    <li>Donec quis mauris ipsum</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the code included in CSS as style.css under css folder:

```
h1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #E14607;
}

h2{
  color: steelblue;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted;
}

ul{
  color: white;
  background-color:steelblue;
}
```

This works perfectly with Chrome, so I'm really not sure what is causing it not to work...
I apreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: What version of IE are you testing on?

Comment: `style="text/css"` should be `type="text/css"` or left off altogether, since you're using HTML 5.

Comment: Have you tried closing the <link> tag?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />`

Comment: @setek thanks, I tried, but no luck

Comment: @DevlshOne yes, tried both but no luck

Comment: Also, take a look at this... http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ ... But with IE11, you shouldn't need any hacks or quirks. It should just work!

Comment: Do you have a public link of your page that we can see?

Answer (score 0):

First replace this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" style="text/css">
```

with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

And also:

> Different browsers may not agree on what some color names mean. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230851/are-there-any-cons-to-using-color-names-in-place-of-color-codes-in-css)

So try changing the color names with hex color like `#f00 or #ff0000`