# Is it better to use #fff rather than "white" and #000 rather than "black"?

Tags: html, css, colors

There may be some use in Sass and Less, but I really think it helps readability if one uses the names.

I see why "orange","gold" or "azure" wouldn't be used, because it's not obvious what hex value they have, but I think black and white should be used in their English written form.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Probably been answered before but I haven't seen it on SO?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230851/are-there-any-cons-to-using-color-names-in-place-of-color-codes-in-css

Comment: Thanks, towerofnix. I found my answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hex colors are already a universal "language" ... no need to over-think this with exceptions. Best to be consistent and always use hex values for everything.